# Postgres query for checking the stocks available after purchase and sell done

Tags: sql, postgresql

please suggest me a way to maintain stocks table which will automatically updates when inserting data into purchase or sell tables, there can be multiple rows insrertion or updation happen, as of now i am using below query to generate stocks records:
somthing like: stocks.qty = sum(purchase.qty) - sum(sell.qty);

```
select ProductName, 
       sum(PQty),
       sum(SQty),
       sum(PQty - SQty)
from (
  select p.product_name as ProductName,
         0 as SQty,
         case when sum(p.qty) is null then 0 else sum(p.qty) end as PQty from purchase p
  group by p.product_name
  
  union
  
  select s.product_name as ProductName, 
         0 as PQty, 
         case when sum(s.qty) is null then 0 else sum(s.qty) end as SQty from sell s
  group by s.product_name
) Stocks
group by ProductName;
```

Comment: Adding sample data might be helpful.

Comment: You really need to ask a better question. We don't know anything about your stock table, and can't just suggest you way to do something without detailed description of what the issue is you're facing.

Comment: @James Z, there is no stocks table maintained as of now, i am asking like how can we create a table which automatically updates the quantity of a product once any insertion or updation happens in purchase or sells table, in case of purchase made it should add up the quantity in stocks table for the same product or make a fresh entry in stocks table in case same product is not there in it, and when a product sold then sells table will update and quantity will be reduced from stocks table.

Comment: @rezu, suppose in purchase table product abc is there with 100 quantity and sells is having abc with 20 quantity then stocks table should have an entry with abc as 80 quantity, if sells is not having any abc product entry then stocks should have abc as 100 quantity, but if sells have abc product with any quantity and purchase do not have abc then it will not appear in stocks table.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the value of products having no sales you need to LEFT JOIN the purchases to the sales rather then attempting to UNION them. You can do this by creating two CTE which get the total purchases and total sold respectively. You then left join the CTEs on product_name. Something like:

```
    with pur(product_name,total_purchased)  as 
         ( select product_name
                , sum(qty) 
             from purchase 
            group by product_name
         ) 
       , sal (product_name,total_sold) as   
        ( select  product_name 
                , sum(qty) 
             from sell 
            group by product_name
         )                  
    select p.Product_Name
         , p.total_purchased
         , coalesce(s.total_sold,0.00) total_sold
         , p.total_purchased -  coalesce(s.total_sold,0.00) stock
      from pur p 
      left join sal s 
        on (p.product_name = s.product_name);
```

This however does NOT maintain the stock levels, but creates an at-this-moment counting.

I suggest abandoning the idea of "maintain stocks table which will automatically updates ...". As maintaining a table gets complex you need to handle not only inserts but also updates and deletes gets complicated. What happens when a purchase is canceled or the a sale has defective product, ...  Basically your a storing a derivable value which is normally a very bad idea.  
Instead create a VIEW that provides the "at-this-moment counting" values when necessary. And by its very nature AUTOMATICALLY adjusts for any activity on either table.

```
create view stock( product_name   
                      , purchases     
                      , sales         
                      , current_stock  
                      ) as 
    with pur(product_name,total_purchased)  as 
         ( select product_name
                , sum(qty) 
             from purchase 
            group by product_name
         ) 
       , sal (product_name,total_sold) as   
        ( select  product_name 
                , sum(qty) 
             from sell
            group by product_name
         )                  
    select p.Product_Name
         , p.total_purchased
         , coalesce(s.total_sold,0.00) 
         , p.total_purchased -  coalesce(s.total_sold,0.00) 
      from pur p 
      left join sal s 
        on (p.product_name = s.product_name);
```

See [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xevxudYDDxmLjSR5t6gEJm/0): For the demo I attempted to generate data so that for any product the sell qty will not exceed the purchase qty. However, the values are generated via random(), so there are this is not  guaranteed.

Comment: thank you so much, it helped a lot, such a nice and through explanation.